# Single physical image jQuery hover fade?

Tags: jquery, image, fade

I have a single  with the active state above the hover state, and the css telling it to move up when you hover over...

```
<a href="#"><img width="220" height="330" src="thumb.jpg" class="img-thumb"/></a> 

a{ float:left;  height:165px;  margin-bottom:20px;  overflow:hidden;  width:220px}

img{ border:none;  margin:0;  opacity:1}

a:hover img{ margin-top:-165px}
```

Works great hover over, changes to the lower part of the image fine.

Is there any jQuery i can add to fade that, make the hover not so harsh, fade to the lower image?

Any ideas?

Thank you :)

Comment: You are actually moving the image up (by adjusting the margin), so any jQuery transition would involve animating the image to it's final hover resting place, which I believe will be up.

Answer (score 0):

here you go ... without using css3 this is your best bet

http://jsfiddle.net/PgnZp/

Comment: Hmm that slides the image up, is there no way to fade it from the one state to the other?

CSS3 would be fine, doesn't have to be jQuery...